# why am I getting undefined on this function?

Tags: javascript, promise, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, airtable

I'm building a dialogflow agent that uses Airtable as database (library: airtable js)

Everything works fine except I can't get the value "out of" the function in order to send it back to the dialogflow agent.

**Function**

```
function showSinglePrice(agent) {
    var finalPrice;
    var arraySinglePrice = null;

    const item = agent.context.get("item"),
      place = item.parameters.place,
      size = item.parameters.size,
      type = item.parameters.type;

    base(tablePlaces)
      .select({
        maxRecords: 10,
        view: viewName,
        filterByFormula: `AND({type} = "${type}",{size} = "${size}",{place} = "${place}")` 
      })
      .firstPage(function(error, records) {
        if (error) {
          response.send({ error: error });
        } else {
          arraySinglePrice = records.map(record => {
            return {
              price: record.get("price")
            };
          });

          console.log(arraySinglePrice); //this works fine

          finalPrice = arraySinglePrice[0].price; //this works fine

          return finalPrice;
        }
      });   
   
    agent.add(`I wanted to get the result in here: ${finalPrice}`); //undefined
  }
```

I'm new to asynchronous programming, so I'm probably messing up with the Airtable js promises, but can't figure it out how to get it to work.

Would appreciate any help

**EDIT**

THANKS @PRISONER FOR THE HELP.

FOR THOSE IN NEED, HERE IS THE WORKING CODE:

```
function showSinglePrice(agent) {    

    const item = agent.context.get("item"),
      place = item.parameters.place,
      size = item.parameters.size,
      type = item.parameters.type;

    return base(tablePlaces) //defined variable before this function
      .select({
        maxRecords: 1, //just want 1
        view: viewName, //defined variable before this function
        filterByFormula: `AND({type} = "${type}",{size} = "${size}",{place} = "${place}")`
      })
      .firstPage()
      .then(result => {
        
        console.log(result);

        var getPrice = result[0].fields.price;

        agent.add(`the current price is: $ ${getPrice}`); //its working
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);

        response.json({
          fulfillmentMessages: [
            {
              text: {
                text: ["We got the following error..."] //will work on it
              }
            }
          ]
        });
      });
  }
```

Comment: Move the `agent.add()` inside `firstPage` callback and replace the `return` with it The `return finalPrice` has nowhere to return to and you are calling add() before all the select chain has completed

Comment: Thanks, Charlie. If I do that, I get the following error: 

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No responses defined for platform: null

 at V2Agent.sendResponses_ (/rbd/pnpm-volume/54a37ce2-dee9-4e33-af7f-21d280ce7234/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/dialogflow-fulfillment/0.6.1/node_modules/dialogflow-fulfillment/src/v2-agent.js:243:13)

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct, there are some issues with how you're using Promises. You're using a callback function in your call to `firstPage()` instead of having it return a Promise. So you could have written that part to look something like this:

```
  .firstPage()
  .then( records => {
    // Work with the records here
  })
  .catch( err => {
    // Deal with the error
  });
```

Once you're dealing with Promises, everything you want to do must be done inside the `.then()` block. So you'll need to move the `agent.add()` in there.

You *also* need to return the Promise, so Dialogflow knows that theres an asynchronous operation taking place. Since the `.then()` and `.catch()` functions return a Promise, you can just return the result of the whole expression. So something like

```
  return base(tablePlaces)
      .select(query)
      .firstPage()
      .then(/*function*/)
      .catch(/*function*/);
```

Comment: don't you get tired saving people's lives? :D

I was struggling for 3 days with that..

tks!

Comment: I'm glad it helped! I just do what little I can to help people and repay the many people who helped (and still help!) me.